# 15 Coins, 4 are quarters, What is the probability of not picking a quarter in 5 picks?

Tags: probability

Cecil has a 15 coin collection. Four coins are quarters, seven coins are dimes, three are nickels and one is a penny.  Calculate the total possible outcomes if Cecil randomly selects five coins.

This is the question, and I have to calculate the chance of drawing no quarters in 5 selects. I'm not sure if Im going about this in the right way, but would I first divide 11 into 15, since 11 of the 15 are not quarters, and get that percentage? Then continue to do the same, but minus one coin each time? S, 11 /14 the next time, since one non quarter has already been selected?

Please let me know if I am doing this right, and if not how to go about solving this.

Comment: Nearly correct, but at the second time you have $10/14$ because you removed one non-quarter-coin.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But once I have done that 5 times, and gotten all 5 percentages, what do I do then?

Comment: The question you mentioned is different from that in the title.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is selecting *without replacement*:

$$P_{no \text{ } quarter} = \frac{11}{15} \cdot \frac{10}{14} \cdot \frac{9}{13} \cdot \frac{8}{12} \cdot \frac{7}{11}.$$

You can also select *with replacement*:

$$P'_{no \text{ } quarter} = \left(\frac{11}{15}\right)^5.$$

If you're grabbing all five coins at once, then you're selecting without replacement.  But if you return the coin to the pile each time, it's with replacement.

Answer (score 1):

John did a nice job of explaining how to correctly implement your strategy for solving the problem.  Here is an alternative method for solving the problem when the coins are selected without replacement.

There are 
$$\binom{15}{5}$$
ways of selecting five of the fifteen available coins.  Since four of those coins are quarters, the number of ways of selecting no quarters when five coins are selected is the number of ways of selecting five of the other eleven coins in the collection, which is 
$$\binom{11}{5}$$
Hence, the probability of selecting no quarters when five coins are selected from the fifteen available coins is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{11}{5}}{\dbinom{15}{5}}$$